# Crawling for only the title of a page

Tags: php, web-crawler

I've been looking around the internet hoping that this is possible, I basically need to get just the title of a webpage and nothing else.

web crawlers can take a long time performing tasks because they have to load pages before examinining them, this is inefficient for what I am trying to achieve... here's what I have so far

**php code**

```
$url = 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/300702997750#ht_500wt_1156';
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$title = ''; 

if(strlen($str)>0){
   preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$titleArr);
   $title = $titleArr[1];
}
```

I want to know whether it would be possible to crawl only part of a page (for example the first 2000 characters of page).

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: This is mostly going to be bad news. However, you can use "curl_multi" to have several connections running at once, and any time one completes, parse it, then grab a new URL from a queue and start downloading that on.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be fetching the FIRST occurrence of "title" (index 0 of $titleArr)? You're currently fetching the second index (remember, arrays start at 0).

Comment: hmm that's still bad news, running multiple crawls won't speed up anything

Comment: No, but it will make 10 pages takes 5 seconds, instead of 50 seconds. There MAY be a way to "cancel" a download after it reaches a certain size, however, the majority of the download time is just waiting- Actually transferring it takes very little time, but waiting for it to start to come in takes a second or so.

Comment: hmmm the code works fine, index[1] contains the title

Comment: Interesting. Try crawling a page with 2 "title" tags, both different, and see which one you end up with

Comment: Index 1 is fine. From PHPs preg_match docs: `If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.`. He only wants what's in the parenthesized subpattern.

Comment: Oh. I really need to use `reg` and `preg` more. I'm horrible with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use substr to just grab the first 1000 chars, alternatively, you could use

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-500');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

that will only download the first 500 bytes. You can bench that by running something like this extremely ugly rubbish code:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/';
$range = array();
$repeats = 10;

function average($a){
  return array_sum($a)/count($a) ;
}

for ($i=0;$i<$repeats;$i++) {
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-500');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    curl_close($ch);
    $range[] = $time;
}
echo "With range: average = ".round(average($range),2)." seconds (Min: ".round(min($range),2).", Max: ".round(max($range),2).")\n";

$range = array();

for ($i=0;$i<$repeats;$i++) {
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    curl_close($ch);
    $range[] = $time;
}
echo "Without range: average = ".round(average($range),2)." seconds (Min: ".round(min($range),2).", Max: ".round(max($range),2).")\n";
```

If I run that on my site (http://www.focalstrategy.com/), I get:

```
With range: average = 0.38 seconds (Min: 0.35, Max: 0.41)
Without range: average = 0.56 seconds (Min: 0.53, Max: 0.7)
```

Against http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP, I get:

```
With range: average = 0.11 seconds (Min: 0.05, Max: 0.5)
Without range: average = 0.48 seconds (Min: 0.34, Max: 0.78)
```

Against [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) I get:

```
With range: average = 1.31 seconds (Min: 1.1, Max: 1.46)
Without range: average = 1.37 seconds (Min: 1.18, Max: 1.7)
```

and against [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/) I get:

```
With range: average = 1.75 seconds (Min: 1.56, Max: 1.99)
Without range: average = 1.74 seconds (Min: 1.51, Max: 2.14)
```

You can see by testing that SO and eBay don't support range requests.

In summary, sites that support this will get a speed up, those that don't, won't, you'll just get the whole code instead.

Comment: Would this be possible to do without loading the whole page?

Comment: i'll give this a shot, but I need to install curl first

Comment: You'll find it useful to have it installed, almost every project I've written has used it somewhere!

Comment: Ok i wasted a lot of time trying to get curl to work, it turns out I just had to uncomment a line in php.ini. but i've tested this and played with CURLOPT_RANGE range a bit but I can't see a performance increase. are you sure there isn't something missing?

Comment: This works fine when I test it. To be honest, it won't save much time unless you have an extremely large website. It does require that the server supports range requests. Mine does, but seems Stackoverflow doesn't, so your milage may vary. On my website, downloading all of it takes 0.5s, downloading first 500 bytes takes 0.3s.

Comment: that's unlucky, big sites such as ebay probably don't support this feature.

Comment: It depends on the server, but yes, eBay doesn't support this.